# layout background image android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, navigation-drawer

I want to change the default background image of my navigation drawer.

I have a .jpg image (1600x900) in drawable folder. I set `android:background="@drawable/bg_1"` for LinearLayout, but when i debug the app in my device, the image doesn't appear and i have a white background.

This is my nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/AccountInformation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/contatti" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/AccountSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AccountEmail"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AccountName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android Studio"
           android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AccountEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:text="android.studio@android.com" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the layout of the activity (activity_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting `android:background="@drawable/bg_1"` for `NavigationView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attibute `android:background="@drawable/bg_1"` should be in the `NavigationView` view not the `LinearLayout` ViewGroup.

Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry, i explained it bad...I want to change the background of the header. Not for all the navigationDrawer.

Comment: The header, is it the action bar at the top ?

Comment: I also try to set `android:background="@drawable/bg_1"` for the `NavigationView` but the result is the same: white background

Comment: Yes. I mean the default "green" bar at the top where android studio puts also an image, a name and an email.

Comment: I get it know , have you try with another img ?

Comment: The problem is that in the "Graphics Preview" of AndroidStudio I see the background image in the top bar of `NavigationView`, but when i do the debug in my device, the background is white.

Comment: I think that the width of your image is too large for the navigation drawer, so there are maybe white strip at the top and at the bottom of the image, this is that your are seing. In the LinearLayout , instead of `android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"` try `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to see if the image appears.

Comment: I try to use smaller picture and now it works...I don't understand why the other image doesn't work, because it hasn't white strip...Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.
See you have to apply the following:

> android:background="@drawable/bg_1"

to NavigationView block in the other xml file

not to linearLayout which you include as Header Layout in the navigationView

Answer (score 0):

Please try a .png image for that,

or after that check a color code `android:background="#651FFF"`.

Hope this help.